# HTML5 FileReader API & IE Support (reader.readAsBinaryString)

Tags: javascript, html5, file-processing

I have trouble reading the Uploaded File (XLSX) via **FileReader** API's **"readAsBinaryString"** method in **IE10**. "readAsText" method works fine. Has anyone come across this, does IE support this method? Am I missing something. Pls find the snippet below:

```
function handleFileUpload(evt){

    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();

    var files = (evt.target.files || evt.dataTransfer.files);
    var output = [];

    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) { 
        output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ', f.size, '   bytes, last modified: ', f.lastModifiedDate ?                                   
        f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() :   'n/a', '</li>');

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var data = e.target.result;
                        alert("-- Data Length --" + data.length);
           };

         // Read in the XLSX file in Binary Mode.   
         //reader.readAsBinaryString(f);//<-- ***does not work if this method is used in IE10 (10.0.9200.16540C0), but works on Chrome***   
           reader.readAsText(f);//<-- ***Works on both Chrome & IE10 (10.0.9200.16540C0)***

    }//for 

}//handleFileUpload
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with salesforce and would be better served on stackoverflow.com

Comment: I agree, although the II part of the requirement is to send the contents & file back to Force.com (insert the rows in XLSX into Force.com custom Object and the file as an attachment). I shall post it as you suggested, thanks.

Comment: No need to downvote the guy to oblivion...

Answer (score 2):

Try using `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f)`